# xml element attributes into list in python

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml like list, my goad is to put X, and Y of each counterPoint in a list.How do you implement this in python? Thank you in advance.

```
<Assembly>
  <Part ASSEMBLY_POS="A12G3" PART_ID="2612666" PART_POS="Y366" MATERIAL="SN490B" PROFILE="PL12">
    <ContourPoint X="19700.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37863">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_NONE" X="0" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="19700.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="38213">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_NONE" X="0" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="20018.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="38213">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_ARC" X="35" Y="35" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="20018.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37507">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_ARC" X="35" Y="35" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="19820.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37507">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_NONE" X="0" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="19820.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37863">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_ROUNDING" X="15" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
  </Part>

</Assembly>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first approximation could be this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Or from a variable
# root = ET.fromstring(data_as_string)

part = root.getchildren()[0]

points = []
for child in part:
    points.append((float(child.attrib['X']), float(child.attrib['Y'])))

print(points)
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Warning The xml.etree.ElementTree module is not secure against maliciously constructed data. If you need to parse untrusted or unauthenticated data see XML vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you, it does the job as expected it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
# root = ET.fromstring(data_str) # or read from a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using sax parsing that might be a bit simpler for this sort of data.

```
data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Assembly>
<Part ASSEMBLY_POS="A12G3" PART_ID="2612666" PART_POS="Y366" MATERIAL="SN490B" PROFILE="PL12">
    <ContourPoint X="19700.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37863">
    <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_NONE" X="0" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="19700.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="38213">
    <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_NONE" X="0" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="20018.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="38213">
    <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_ARC" X="35" Y="35" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="20018.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37507">
    <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_ARC" X="35" Y="35" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="19820.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37507">
    <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_NONE" X="0" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="19820.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37863">
    <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_ROUNDING" X="15" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
</Part>

</Assembly>
"""

import xml.sax

class AssemblyHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == "Part":
            print("PART")
        elif name == "ContourPoint":
            print(attrs.get('X'), attrs.get('Y'))

xml.sax.parseString(data, AssemblyHandler())
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all the tags with the respective tag names(that has attribute 'X' and 'Y' in this case) and the iterate through the result to get the attribute values to a list using list comprehension!

```
data='''<Assembly>
  <Part ASSEMBLY_POS="A12G3" PART_ID="2612666" PART_POS="Y366" MATERIAL="SN490B" PROFILE="PL12">
    <ContourPoint X="19700.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37863">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_NONE" X="0" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="19700.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="38213">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_NONE" X="0" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="20018.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="38213">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_ARC" X="35" Y="35" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="20018.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37507">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_ARC" X="35" Y="35" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="19820.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37507">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_NONE" X="0" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
    <ContourPoint X="19820.001848" Y="21760.00407" Z="37863">
      <Chamfer DZ1="0" DZ2="0" TYPE="CHAMFER_ROUNDING" X="15" Y="0" />
    </ContourPoint>
  </Part>
</Assembly>'''
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(data)
points = root.findall('.//ContourPoint')
print [(each.attrib['X'],each.attrib['Y']) for each in points]
```

Output:

```
[('19700.001848', '21760.00407'), ('19700.001848', '21760.00407'), ('20018.001848', '21760.00407'), ('20018.001848', '21760.00407'), ('19820.001848', '21760.00407'), ('19820.001848', '21760.00407')]
```